# SE site moderators should have additional privileges on meta.se

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta, moderator-tools

Sometimes moderation of a Stack Exchange site flows over to the main Meta Stack Exchange site (i.e., here). For example, a suspended user might come here to rant and rave about the suspension. Often these questions get closed and eventually deleted. Once the question becomes deleted, it is not possible for a user to see the deleted post without 10k reputation on meta. I think it would be useful if mods at other stack exchange sites automatically could view deleted posts regardless of their reputation on meta.

By being able to see a deleted message, a moderator could refresh themselves on behavior that led to a previous warning or suspension and see if current bad behavior matches previous bad behavior.

Answer (score 21):

This doesn't seem like a particularly compelling use-case to me.

I mean, you're essentially asking to be exposed to more grief from someone you've already dealt with. We could just as well move such questions to the site where you *are* a moderator, thus negating the purpose of you suspending them in the first place.

Folks who actually want to communicate with you over their suspension in a constructive fashion can reply directly to the message you sent them, *or* - if they must post publicly - communicate in a way that doesn't result in their posts being deleted.

Perhaps, when given respite from the drama, you should take advantage of it while it lasts...

Comment: Purging comments from a user who was suspended and unwilling to participate constructively, thus illustrating my point.

Comment: How does one possibly participate constructively in these situations?

Comment: Yeah... Look, this is a sockpuppet account that you created to work around a suspension. You were suspended for being rude and creating sockpuppets to prop up your arguments. You responded with name-calling and vulgarity. So... I guess the answer to "how does one possibly participate constructively" would be "don't be blatantly rude and dishonest just because someone disagrees with you". I don't really care to re-hash whatever little spat *originally* caused you to flip out here; the proper place to do that was on Meta Academia, months ago, with calm, well-reasoned arguments. Oh well.

Comment: Actually, there was no rudeness and vulgarity at that time.  In fact, I had acted exactly as you suggested, by posting on Meta Academia; here is the  link: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3389/should-the-black-nodes-matter-question-be-removed.  It got downvoted aggressively very quickly.  Then I posted a fundamentally same question on Academia, making a mockery of French lives right around the time of the Nice attacks, to bring home the point of my argument.

Comment: So yeah, when I said I had no interest in discussing it here, I meant that. You failed to persuade the folks you needed to persuade, and reacted badly to your failure. That's the bed you made, so lie in it.

Answer (score 15):

I'm a mod - but don't think having additional powers here would help. I don't yet have 10k here, but it doesn't hold me up in dealing with behaviours that may spill over to meta.

We have recourse to CM's, other mods etc anyway. Let's not go overboard on our "modly powers!"

Comment: My exact thinking too (as a mod on two sites).  I'm happy to earn my 10K here if I want to see deleted posts here.